# Double mouse cursor with simple matter.js

Tags: javascript, mouse, matter.js

I wanted to create an idle game with matter.js. I can perfectly capture mouse events, and then started noticing that there is a double cursor after I single click the portal in the center. Even after taking out all the code related to capturing mouse events, I still see a duplicate cursor. I dumbed down the code to the minimum, I still have no clue where this could come from.

The provided sample is best tested in Chrome, Edge for some reason ignores my black background directive in css.

```js
// Install plugin
  Matter.use('matter-attractors');// PLUGIN_NAME
  Matter.use('matter-collision-events');// PLUGIN_NAME

  // module aliases
  var Engine = Matter.Engine,
      Events = Matter.Events,
      Runner = Matter.Runner,
      Render = Matter.Render,
      World = Matter.World,
      Body = Matter.Body,
      //Mouse = Matter.Mouse,
      Common = Matter.Common,
      Bodies = Matter.Bodies;
      //MouseConstraint = Matter.MouseConstraint;

  function UI() {
    listenToResize();

    // Create engine
    this.engine = Engine.create();

    // Create renderer
    this.render = Render.create({
      element: document.body,
      engine: this.engine,
      options: {
        width: document.documentElement.clientWidth,
        height: document.documentElement.clientHeight,
        wireframes: false,
        background: 'black',
        showId: true
      }
    });

    //Link engine and renderer
    this.engine.render = this.render;

    // Create runner
    this.runner = Runner.create();
    // Do the running
    Runner.run(this.runner, this.engine);
    Render.run(this.render);

    // Create demo scene
    this.world = this.engine.world;
    this.world.gravity.scale = 0;

    World.add(this.world, UI.createPortal(this));

  }

  function listenToResize() {

    function captureSize() {
      console.log("Resize captured!");
      UI.height = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight;
      UI.width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;
      UI.centerX = UI.width >> 1;
      UI.centerY = UI.height >> 1;
    }

    window.addEventListener("optimizedResize", captureSize);

    captureSize();
  }

  UI.createPortal = function createPortalUI(ui) {

    // create a body with an attractor
    return Bodies.circle(ui.render.options.width / 2, ui.render.options.height / 2, 50, {
      isStatic: true,
      label: 'centerPortal',
      id:'centerPortal',
      render: {
        sprite: {
          texture: '//konijn.github.io/needle-eye/SVGMerchant/png/star-gate.png',
          xScale: 0.1,
          yScale: 0.1,
          showId: true
        }
      },

      // example of an attractor function that
      // returns a force vector that applies to bodyB
      //Todo recognize non attracted thingies
      plugin: {
        attractors: [// MatterAttractors.Attractors.gravity(bodyA, bodyB)
        function(bodyA, bodyB) {
          return {
            x: (bodyA.position.x - bodyB.position.x) * 1e-6,
            y: (bodyA.position.y - bodyB.position.y) * 1e-6,
          };
        }
        ]
      }
    });
  };

  UI.log = function(txt, x, y) {
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    let content = document.createTextNode(txt);
    div.classList.add('message');
    div.appendChild(content);
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    UI.animateLog();
  }

  UI.animateLog = function animateLog() {
    if (UI.interval)
      return;

    UI.interval = window.setInterval(UI.animateLogItems, 100);
  }

  UI.animateLogItems = function animateLogItems() {
    let list = document.getElementsByClassName('message');
    for (e of list) {
      //console.log(e);
      if (e.offsetTop < 5) {
        document.body.removeChild(e);
      } else {
        e.style.top = (e.offsetTop - 1) + 'px';
      }
    }
  }

  UI.remove = function(body){
    World.remove(ui.world, body);
  }

  /*
    Inspiration : Merchant RPG
    http://brm.io/matter-js/docs/index.html
    https://game-icons.net/
    https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/321
  */
  /*jshint esversion: 6 */

  var game = new Game(),
      data = game.data,
      ui   = new UI();

  function Game() {

    this.updateInterval = setInterval(update, 1000);
    this.data = {};
  }

  Game.prototype.onClick = function onClick(body){
    console.log(body);
    if(body.label=="centerPortal"){
      //UI.createImp(ui);
      //UI.log('You summoned an Imp');
    }
    if(body.label.startsWith('Imp,')){
      UI.createLog(ui);
      UI.remove(body);
    }
  };

  function update() {
    //console.log('Tick');
    if (!data.gameStarted) {
      message('Welcome to Portal Merchant');
      message('You see a start portal');
      message('You feel compelled to activate it');

    }
  }

  function message(msg) {

  }

  function load() {
    return scaffoldLoad(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data') || "{}"));
  }

  function save() {
    localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(scaffoldSave(data)));
  }

  function reset() {
    localStorage.removeItem('data');
  }

  function help() {
    console.log("Console commands:");
    console.log("reset()");
  }

  function scaffoldLoad(data) {
    return data;
  }

  function scaffoldSave(data) {
    return data;
  }

  function step(timestamp) {
    UI.last = UI.last || timestamp;
    let progress = timestamp - UI.last;
  }
```

```css
/* Pretty colors and such */
body {
  background-color: black;
  /* Foreground is 'merino' */
  color: rgb(225, 219, 208);
  height: 100%
  background: black;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

canvas {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

canvas:active {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.message {
  position:absolute;
  background-color: black;
  color: rgb(225, 219, 208);  
  z-index: 2; 
  bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
    <meta name="description" content="Merchant">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Merchant</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="merch.css" media="screen"/>
    <!-- <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.12.0/matter.min.js"></script> -->
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.12.0/matter.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/liabru/matter-attractors/master/build/matter-attractors.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/matter-collision-events@0.1.7/build/matter-collision-events.min.js"></script>
    Single click the portal in the center, you should see a double cursor, why??
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was `canvas:active {}`, the `active` keyword doubles the cursor.